# Obtener múltiples veces datos de firebase en un For(Loop) usando ReactJS

Tags: nodejs, firebase, reactjs

En uno de mis objetos en la base de datos de firebase, tengo tags de empresas que su funcionalidad es describir a estas empresas de mejor manera, al trata de obtener datos de manera individual de cada tag en un For(loop) el servicio me retorna null, pero al hardcodear toda la ruta el servicio si responde de manera correcta.

Los console.log me muestran los valores de las variables de manera correcta y todo pareciera estar correcto hasta el punto en el que se ejecuta la petición.

```
  empresasMunicipio = async (lst_tags,id_empresa,nombreEmpresa)=>{
    try {
      var empresaByMunicipio: any = {};
      empresaByMunicipio.id_empresa = id_empresa;
      empresaByMunicipio.isTest = true;
      empresaByMunicipio.nombre = nombreEmpresa;

      for (var index = 0; index < lst_tags.length; index++) {
          var item = lst_tags[index].id_tag;
          console.log(`tags/lst_tags/${item}`);
          var refTags = await this.props.firebase.db().ref(`tags/lst_tags/${item}`);
          await refTags.once("value", snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
          });
      }
    } catch (error) {

    }
  }
```

Esto funciona

```
var refTags = await this.props.firebase.db().ref(`tags/lst_tags/${"-LKd4Z9OOpZMV-_DYE10"}`);
          await refTags.once("value", snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
          });
```

Esto no funciona

```
var refTags = await this.props.firebase.db().ref(`tags/lst_tags/${item}`);
          await refTags.once("value", snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
          });
```

Comment: que pasa si agregas lo siguiente ``tags/lst_tags/${item}/``

Comment: Gaston sigue retornando un null, al parecer el error proviene del ciclo "For" ya que si solo fuera una única petición no habría problema, así lo hago en otros puntos de mi aplicación, pero no entiendo porque el "For" evita de alguna manera un retorno correcto de los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me van a disculpar pero fue el error más tonto de toda mi vida que me hizo perder 1 dia entero, al ingresar la información en el formulario y pasarlo a un función previa a "empresasMunicipio", está hace un uppercase y por lo tanto el path jamás iba a ser correcto, por eso si se hardcodeaba corria perfecto pero con la variable fallaba, una sincera disculpa a todos los que perdieron su tiempo tratando de solucionar el código.

La ruta correcta era esta:

```
console.log(`tags/lst_tags/${"-LKd4Z9OOpZMV-_DYE10"}`);
"tags/lst_tags/-LKd4Z9OOpZMV-_DYE10"
```

La ruta impresa por el console.log y teniendo la variable era esta:

```
console.log(`tags/lst_tags/${item}`);
"tags/lst_tags/-LKD4Z9OOPZMV-_DYE10"
```

2 de las letras cambiaban de minusculas a mayusculas.